# Read in csv file using pandas having issues with close columns

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have the foll. csv file:

```
RUN   YR    AP15    PMTE
   12008    4.53    0.04
   12009    3.17    0.26
   12010    6.20    1.38
   12011    5.38    3.55
   12012    7.32    6.13
   12013    4.39    9.40
```

Here, the column 'YR' has the values 2008, 2009...2013. However, there is no space between the values for YR and values for RUN. Because of this, when I try to read in the dataframe, it does not read the YR column correctly.

```
pandas.read_csv('file.csv', skipinitialspace=True, usecols=['YR','PMTE'], sep=' ')
```

The line above reads in the AP15 column instead of YR. How do I fix this?

Comment: Your csv file does not represent what you expect it to do - there should be a delimiter between the columns if there are two columns. I guess you can't fix your csv file?

Comment: that's the problem, I cant fix the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One workaround you can do for this would be to first make the column `RUN` and `YR` as one for your csv . Example -

```
   RUNYR    AP15    PMTE
   12008    4.53    0.04
   12009    3.17    0.26
   12010    6.20    1.38
   12011    5.38    3.55
   12012    7.32    6.13
   12013    4.39    9.40
```

Then read the csv into a dataframe with `RUNYR` as a string column, and then slice the `RUNYR` column up to make two different columns using [`pandas.Series.str.slice`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.slice.html) method. Example -

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', skipinitialspace=True, header=0, sep=' ',dtype={'RUNYR':str})

df['RUN'] = df['RUNYR'].str.slice(None,1).astype(int)
df['YR'] = df['RUNYR'].str.slice(1).astype(int)

df = df.drop('RUNYR',axis=1)
```

Demo -

```
In [21]: df = pd.read_csv('a.csv', skipinitialspace=True, header=0, sep=' ',dtype={'RUNYR':str})

In [22]: df['RUN'] = df['RUNYR'].str.slice(None,1).astype(int)

In [23]: df['YR'] = df['RUNYR'].str.slice(1).astype(int)

In [24]: df = df.drop('RUNYR',axis=1)

In [25]: df
Out[25]:
   AP15  PMTE  RUN    YR
0  4.53  0.04    1  2008
1  3.17  0.26    1  2009
2  6.20  1.38    1  2010
3  5.38  3.55    1  2011
4  7.32  6.13    1  2012
5  4.39  9.40    1  2013
```

And then write this back to your csv using [`.to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) method (to fix your csv permanently) .

Answer (score 3):

It seems like your 'csv' is really a fixed-width format file. Sometimes these are accompanied by another file listing the size of each column, but maybe you aren't that lucky, and have to count the column widths manually. You can read this file with `pandas`'s fixed width reading function:

```
df = pd.read_fwf('fixed_width.txt', widths=[4, 4, 8, 8])

In [7]: df
Out[7]: 
   RUN    YR  AP15  PMTE
0    1  2008  4.53  0.04
1    1  2009  3.17  0.26
2    1  2010  6.20  1.38
3    1  2011  5.38  3.55
4    1  2012  7.32  6.13
5    1  2013  4.39  9.40

In [8]: df.columns
Out[8]: Index(['RUN', 'YR', 'AP15', 'PMTE'], dtype='object')
```

There is an option to find the widths automatically but it probably requires at least a space between each column, as it doesn't seem to work here.